# What is the difference between a branch and a sub branch in tree structure terminology

Tags: tree

Sometimes when you read an article you find:

"The T-tree differs from more standard set enumeration
trees in that the nodes at the same level in any sub-branch
are organised into 1-D arrays so that array indexes represent
column numbers."
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1250965/

"...in a tree, there is a branch. in the branch, there is another subbranch"

"...where a branch splits into two branches where one of the branches becomes a sub-branch"

So what is the difference between a branch and sub branch in tree structure terminology?

Comment: I'm not sure this terminology is applied everywhere, e.g. I haven't heard this much being used on tree questions here on SO.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi Tim, I updated my question. I referred to one paper where they use this term. could you check it.

Comment: Hi Mosab, I don't have time to read the paper at the moment, but this may just be their own arbitrary terminlogy.  If you don't have a real life computer science problem involving it, I wouldn't lose sleep over it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok dear, so for the time being, can we say that the branch is same as a sub-branch (because even me I didn't hear about sub-branches before)

Comment: Well how are these terms being used in the paper?  Isn't that a better source of informatiom than SO?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actually they didn't introduce this term in the paper, as if it is known before, and they use it once.